# Recover Primal Linear Programming Solution from Dual with LAD Regression?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, linear-regression

[This](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-lad-regression.html) link discusses different ways of writing a classic LAD regression with a linear program. The classic way of writing LAD regression ($y = X \beta + r$) as a linear program is
\begin{equation}
\min_{r, \beta} \sum_i r_i 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{subject to } -r \leq y - X \beta \leq r
\end{equation}

It is mentioned that the dual problem is
\begin{equation}
\max_{d} y^T d
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{subject to } X^T d = 0 \text{ and } -1 \leq d_i \leq 1
\end{equation}

My question is simple: if you solve the dual problem (it is much faster computationally), how exactly do you recover $\beta$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\min\limits_{r, \beta}$? It is not mentioned at the link and it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Put simply, it means to choose r and beta by minimizing the given quantity. It discusses how only X and y are fixed, all other variables are free variables. This is my understanding anyway.